# Confusion about boundary condition of magnetic flux density $B$ and magnetic field intensity $H$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, boundary-conditions

Suppose we have a long solenoid of length $L$ with a current $I$, radius $r_1$ and $N$ turns. Suppose we introduce a core with radius $r_2<r_1$ and permeability $\mu$. Then, there will be two regions: one with the core ($r\geq r_2$), and one with air ($r_2\geq r \geq r_1 $). Ampere's law says that
$$\oint _{loop} \overrightarrow{H}\cdot \overrightarrow{dl}=IN$$

If we choose the loop to be rectangular, then $\overrightarrow{H}=\dfrac{IN}{L}$. In the region with the core, $H=\dfrac{B}{\mu}$, which would imply $B=\dfrac{IN\mu}{L}$. In the region with air, $B=\dfrac{IN\mu_0}{L}$. Hence, the normal component of $B$ is discontinous as we go from one medium to the other.

I know this is not correct, and the normal component of $B$ shouldn't be discontinuous, but I am not sure where my formulation is wrong. I'd appreciate if someone can help clarify my confusion.

I added an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFTMg.png) for clarification. So, if the core were to be half way (up to length $\dfrac{L}{2}$), how would the calculation change? Because the current enclosed would still be the same.

Thanks

Comment: But the axial component of $B$ is indeed not continuous across the boundary where $\mu$ is not continuous. Why do you think this is not correct?

Comment: But doesn't the boundary condition say that $B_{1n}=B_{2n}$, that is the normal component of $B$ is equal when going from one medium to the other? Suppose the field $H$ is oriented in the $x$ direction. If we go radially, then at first we'll be in region I (the core), as we go on, we move to region II (air). Shouldn't $B$ be the same in both regions? I can add a picture, if what I am describing is not clear.

Comment: Yes normal component behaves like you describe. But the field is axial, which means when we go from region 1 to region 2 this field is parallel to the boundary. So this parallel field has a jump, but the normal field is continuous (and almost zero).

Comment: oh, that makes sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited the original question added a follow-up question, Could you please take a look?

Comment: If the core is half-length then the original result is still approximately correct on the axis-normal planes close to core's center but less near core's faces. Above them in the air the H field has a source so it is stronger than H field in the core, and its lines diverge and wrap around as dipole field does. If core is ferromagnetic, H field looks almost like electric field would if charge was concentrated on the flat faces.

Comment: What if I apply Ampere's law? Because Ampere's law is still going to tell me that $H=\dfrac{NI}{L}$ since the current enclosed is the same. Or am I getting something wrong? I asked a separate question, just to make my confusion clearer and not extend this discussion too much. The new question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/612230/boundary-conditions-of-magnetic-field-inside-a-solenoid-with-a-core If you have time, I'd appreciate if you can take a look.

Comment: Ampere's law is valid but it isn't possible to apply it like that because H isn't uniform. Its magnitude and direction depends on position.

Comment: Yes, but if you choose a rectangular loop, you will enclose the same current, regardless of the exact position of the loop. That's why the magnetic field of a solenoid is given by $B=\dfrac{NI\mu_0}{L}$, or am I wrong?

Comment: Same current will be enclosed, but you cannot express the line integral as HL, because $\mathbf H$ varies in direction and magnitude.